# Google datastore unindexed properties

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I writting an app engine use datastore , but when I save a long byte string in blob value . I get error "Indexed Blob Value has more than 500 character " . then I setIndexed(false) in the property but nothing change . I use PHP client library

```
$string_prop = new Google_Service_Datastore_Property();
$indexed = false ;
$string_prop->setIndexed($indexed);
var_dump($string_prop->getIndexed());
$dk = 'To improve performance ' ;
$string_prop->setBlobValue(base64_encode($dk));
```

Comment: I'd like to help but where is the Google_Service_Datastore_Property() function documented please?  My search-fu is weak today.

Comment: yes , I read it but this is setindexed function : public function public function setIndexed($indexed)
  {
    $this->indexed = $indexed;
  }  there is no content

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) (beta) PHP client library?

Comment: yes , this is the library [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)   . is there any problem with beta client library ? @tx802

Comment: @tx802 please give me an explain